# How to open a file in the current editor panel from the Explorer in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I can select the explorer tab in Visial Studio Code by pressing `CMD+0`.

From there I can open a file ***in a new editor tab***  by pressing `CTRL+Enter`.

`Enter` starts renaming
`CMD+o` shows the open file window

But how can I just open the file ***in the current editor panel*** without creating a new tab?

We can see in the screenshot that the "selected" (silhouetted) file in the *Explorer* panel was able to be opened via `CTL-Enter`: but it is in a **new editor panel** to the right :

![enter image description here

[image]
Let's open another file now using `CTL-Enter`:  we can see there are now ***three*** editor panels:

[image]

That's clearly going to get problematic pretty rapidly..

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Are you just looking for `CMD+P`?  To open some file.

Comment: By pressing CMD+0 I activate the explorer (this is different from CMD+P). There I can highlight the filIe I want to open by using the up and down arrows. But how do I open a file?

Comment: I concur with this question: the _Explorer_ panel  does not allow opening the existing file in the _current_ editor tab.  I have added a screenshot here to clarify

Answer (score 1):

Its "SPACE". At least in  my installation.

The corresponding setting is `filesExplorer.openFilePreserveFocus`

Comment: Clarification for other readers:  hitting the _space-bar_ in the _Explorer_ panel will open the file in the existing editor panel